# Set checkpoint lanes in a highway for a veh flow in Eclipse Sumo

Tags: eclipse, simulation, sumo, checkpoint

My simulation consists of a 5-lane, 10 km long highway with different vehicle flows.
I want one veh flow to pass through 2nd lane at 3 km, through 4th lane at 6 km and to arrive at 3rd lane at 10 km. Some kind of "checkpoints" inside the highway.
I have managed to set only the arrival target lane (3rd) in the route file of simulation by writing arrivalLane="4" in specs of the flow.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to define waypoints in sumo by adding a stop to a vehicle with a speed attribute https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes.html#waypoints